# Every Rose has its Thorn - is dawn negative?

Tags: lyrics, meaning

The song [*Every Rose has its Thorn*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZcqWyyHlCDA) by **Poison** appears to be talking about the disappointment of loss of love. During the chorus it appears to be talking about negative aspects of this:

> Every rose has its thorn
>   Just like every night has its dawn
>   Just like every cowboy sings his sad, sad song
>   Every rose has its thorn

But the middle allusion is commonly considered a positive, night being negative and dawn signaling the end of the night.

Is this another negative, and if so why? If it’s not negative, what is the purpose of this phrase in this sequence of allusions?

Comment: I've always wondered about that one too.  It's not the only song with that kind of unexpected valence reversal, either.  [I Guess That's Why They Call It the Blues](https://genius.com/Elton-john-i-guess-thats-why-they-call-it-the-blues-lyrics) and [How Do You Mend a Broken Heart](https://genius.com/Al-green-how-can-you-mend-a-broken-heart-lyrics) are similarly puzzling that way...

Answer (score 6):

*Personal interpretation*

The night is seen as somewhow positive since it symbolises the last time where the lovers spend time together.

The first verse says:

> **We both lie silently still**
>   **In the dead of the night**
>   Although we both lie close together
>   We feel miles apart inside

It seems that they spend their last night together and at dawn they decided to break up, so dawn is associated with the separation.

> I know I could have saved a love that night
>   If I'd known what to say
>   **Instead of makin' love**
>   **We both made our separate ways**